# Can a chord B C F with B as a root note exist?

Tags: theory, chord-theory

In the key of C:
C E G is the tonic and can be denoted as just C

C D G is Csus2, meaning the third degree of a chord is removed and a second is added. It also follows the sus2 chord formula, which is M2 P4.

But at the note B, while technically B C F follows the rules of removing the third degree and replacing it with the second, it's not a chord that has a name if you're starting from B.

It also doesn't follow the sus2 formula and instead is composed of m2 P4.

How is such a chord denoted and what determines that name? Because apparently it's not just removing the third degree and adding the second that makes it sus2 as I've thought.

Comment: Interesting question and responses. I’ll just comment rather than answer. The dictionary says: Definition of chord: three or more musical tones sounded simultaneously. It’s a chord by definition and exists. As far as naming it, first it’s important to point out that chord symbols are independent of key so referencing the key of C is irrelevant in the naming of this chord. Something this unusual is probably best written out on the staff but if you want a chord symbol it could be a B chord or an inversion with a B in the bass. My preference is a B chord, not an inversion, Bdim(b9)(omit3).

Comment: Plot twist: note names do not identify frequencies. While most musicians will, by default, assume the "well temperament", there are dozens of well-knows tunings - and you can design your own if your music needs it. However, I am not ware of any of the more popular tunings in which a B-C is considered harmonic. But: "Harmonically, the interval usually occurs as some form of dissonance or a nonchord tone that is not part of the functional harmony. It may also appear in inversions of a major seventh chord, and in many added tone chords." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitone#Minor_second)

Comment: @Klaws B-C as a prime or ninth is generally dissonant (whereas C-B as a seventh or fourteenth is pretty consontant in any Ptolemaic / meantone tuning, hence the frequent use of maj7 chords in many genres), but chords _can_ of course be dissonant. B-c-f works pretty well as a dominant chord, resolving B→C | c→b | f→e to a maj7 chord.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chord-naming generally serves two purposes:

1. To indicate the pitches to play, and
2. To indicate the function of those pitches.

Allowing in this case that the goal is to get the chord-player to play B-C-F specifically, and in that voicing, then the most likely chord name would be something like Bdim[sus(b2)] or maybe B[sus(b2)][#4], which would sound the same result. Either of those would be likely give pause to the reader, but ultimately communicate exactly which pitches to play.

Alternatively, we might interpret chords as "stacks" of thirds. In that case, this could could be named B7(b5)(b9) or B-7(b5)(b9), where the performer decides to omit the 3rd and 7th in favor of a more "open", fifths-based sound (B-F-C).

Functionally, this chord seems most likely to occur in C major. It would be a vii chord, but with the third (D) replaced by an anticipation of the C in the chord of resolution. In that case, it might be best to call the chord Csus4/B. Although that obscures the idea that B is the root, it would better communicate the context/intent.

---

EDIT

Following on a comment by @user1079505 (to the answer by said @user1079505)

> Perhaps look for materials about ... XX century music developments?

If you *really* want to name the chord precisely, then it's T<sub>e</sub>([016]).

Comment: More usually, it's the 3rd and the 7th which define a chord (along with root), so giving the player the option on both seems odd, or even irresponsible. With both a guitarist and a keyboard player playing simultaneously the results could be quite - interesting!

Answer (score 4):

Chords are named after the intervals they contain. A sus2 chord has a major second and a perfect fifth. If you start with a B chord (B, D#, F#) and replace the third with a second, you end up with B, C#, F#, a Bsus2 chord.

Your chord, B,C,F with a B root, has a minor second and a diminished fifth so it's not a sus2 chord. In fact it has no name, but that doesn't mean it's not a chord.

Comment: i don't find it musically appropriate i just wanna know what determines how a chord is called. is it just its formula?

Comment: @Anonymous The intervals determine the name. There is no name for this particular combination of intervals.

Answer (score 4):

The basic *triad* generally contains a root, a third and a fifth. Hence your C major chord - C E G, C- root, E -M3, G - P5. Minor chords simply change the M3 to a m3.

Sus chords usually replace the 3 with a P4.

Assuming the B in your chord is root, the 3 is missing, and not relaced by a diatonic 2, but a m2, and the P5 has become D5. No 'ordinary' chord ! And, it hardly stands on its own, as most triad chords can.

At a push, using C as its root (but not lowest note, that's different), it could be a C chord - of some description. There's no 3rd, but the F could be sus4. There's no 5, but that often is omitted. The B could then be major7. Which gets it named as Cmaj7sus/B - at a push.

If it can be played, then, yes, it exists. Any set of notes played together will be a chord - but naming it, and using it in a meaningful context, is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: doesn't diatonic mean it exists within the scale? the scale in this case is C major so C as a 2nd degree of B D F would be diatonic

Comment: @Anonymous - diatonic does mean that. But since you made B the root, I took that as being the tonic of the scale, rather than C. So the scale I refer to is B. Exactly as your accepted answer does. My suggestion as to its name takes us back, diatonically, to key C.

Comment: the answer i've accepted just explains how sus chords are created, which is using a formula instead of suspending the 3rd degree and replacing it with 2nd no matter on which scale degree you currently are. and that was exactly the question, following the rules of suspending 3rd degree and adding 2nd doesnt give u sus2 on every scale degree. on E it would be sus2(b2) and on B its a nonexistent chord which could alternatively be called Fsus4(#4)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand all of your last comment. A 'sus2' chord is actualy a misnomer - it should be called ret2, but it's becoe acceptable to call a chord sus2 when the 3rd is replaced by a diatonic 2. Don't get your last bit - Fsus4 needs Bb. The sus (or ret) part will *only* refer to the replacement of the **3rd** from a triad, not that particular note in whatever key. So Fsus4 will have its A note replaced by Bb. If a chord still has its 3rd, and there's a 4th *as well*, it gets called an 11th chord. Hope I read it all right.

Comment: the sus2 chord as i understand means that a 3rd degree is suspended and replaced with 2nd or 4th before being resolved back to the 3rd. in modern music however sus2 or sus4 can exist without ever being resolved. going back to the Fsus4(#4) name, the notes are B C F, the chord could be called Fsus4(#4) because the 4th degree of F major scale would be Bb but its B in this case hence #4. but that does mean B is no longer the root note

Comment: i also don't know where you've got the idea i'm removing a note from a scale, i've specifically said that building a chord from E and replacing the third which is G with F which would be diatonic to C major gives us Esus2(b2)

Comment: @Anonymous - no. sus2 can mean only one thing. The 3rd has been taken out, and replaced by the 2nd. But it's actually not a suspension. If you build the chord from E, the G(#) cannot be replaced by F, as the second note in key E is F#. it's a retardation. To replace the 3rd with the 4th it gets called sus4 (suspended 4). Fsus4(#4) is somewhat nonsensical. Any resolution or not isn't part of what we're discussing.

Comment: @Tim 'ret2' night be the theoretical correct term for a 'sus2' chord, but in practice 'sus2' is almost always used (in fact I've never seen 'ret2' outside of this forum)

Comment: @PiedPiper - yes, as I stated in a comment, sus 2 is commonplace.. However, OP thinks that sus 2 means 3rd degree is replaced by **either** 2 **or** 4. As OP says, 'not that great in music theory'. So why all the arguments, I don't know.

Comment: This is the right answer: Cmaj7sus4/B with G omitted. A suitable chord for the moment you discover the object of your love is the person who murdered your spouse.

Answer (score 4):

In modal terminology you could call it the *locrian chord* as it contains the characteristic tones of the locrian mode: flat 2 and a tritone. Lydian also prominently features a tritone with the root, but lacks the equally prominent flat 2 of locrian. Similarly, phrygian shares the prominent flat 2, but has both a perfect 4 and 5.

Trying to squeeze these notes into functional harmony naming is certainly possible, but it's a stretch. What is the point? Unless the notes B-C-F are only a part of some larger chord structure, like Bm7b5b9?

Comment: the point is to see whether naming a chord with 1 2 and 5 degrees sus2 is possible from every scale degree. I thought that any chord with suspended 3rd and added 2nd is called sus2 but at the vii i got confused as ive never seen a chord like Bdim[sus(b2)] before

Comment: Suggested edit: The b2 is not the only distinction between Locrian and Lydian -- Lydian has #4; Locrian has b5.

Comment: @Anonymous sus chords are a weird animal as well. What is a sus? In some cases it means the third is delayed. In other cases it means _coexistence_ of third and the avoid note. I would say you shouldn't try too hard describe your chord with functional harmony. Perhaps look for materials about modal harmony. Perhaps about XX century music developments?

Comment: @Aaron thanks, you're right, but I don't know how to phrase it well. For me a tritone is a tritone... Go ahead and edit the post, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are excellent, and as they say there are multiple ways of naming chords.

Assuming the notes are all in the same octave in the order B,C F, this is probably (as Tim suggests) **best** considered the third inversion of Cmaj7, with 4th substituted for the 3rd and the G omitted.

You might write that Cmaj7sus4/B.

When might you use this very strange chord?

The major 7 chord is sometimes called "the love chord" and often appears in transition from e.g. C, Cmaj7, C7. It evokes feelings of longing. Think of "Black is the colour of my true love's hair", "Hello", or "I don't want to talk about it"

The sus4 has a questioning/unresolved quality and suggests something is in doubt or is changing. Also often used in a transition or sequence e.g. C,Csus4,C or C,Csus4,C,Csus2,Am.

To my ear the combination has a foreboding quality, as if something bad is about to happen. Perhaps the protagonist has just discovered that that the object of her love is the actually the murderer of her husband! Use sparingly.